# Controlling breaks in a multi-column layout generated by the jQuery plugin Textify.js

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-plugins, joomla, multiple-columns

I am using the textify.js jQuery plugin available on CodeCanyon and I am having problems managing how text-based content breaks in a multi-column, multi-page layout.

One of the most pressing problems I am having relates to lists. Sometimes, list items break incorrectly.

In the code below, columns are set to a fixed height of 330px. Some of the list items break mid-item and are continued on the next column. The result is a new list item is started on the next column when that happens.

```
<ul>
    <li>Vous raccommoder avec votre conjoint après avoir exprimé clairement vos attentes de changement, en surmontant vos différends.</li>
    <li>Consulter un tiers autorisé (psychologue, conseiller familial, prêtre) à titre individuel pour faire le point sur votre situation personnelle.</li>
    <li>Consulter un conseiller/médiateur familial avec votre conjoint.</li>
    <li>Vous séparer de fait (sans requérir l'intervention d'un juge, et avec ou sans une convention écrite avec votre conjoint).</li>
    <li>Requérir du juge des mesures protectrices de l'union conjugale  (en demandant ou non  l'attribution du logement familial, c'est-à-dire en menant ou non une vie séparée).</li>
    <li>À noter que requérir des mesures protectrices de l'union conjugale pour organiser la vie séparée peut-être un moyen de préparer un divorce unilatéral si le conjoint refuse de divorcer.</li>
    <li>Si les conditions en sont réalisées, introduire une action en séparation de corps (cas échéant d'accord avec votre conjoint).</li>
</ul>
```

Effectively, it breaks and creates a new `<li>` as such:

```
<ul>
    <li>Vous raccommoder avec votre conjoint après avoir exprimé clairement vos attentes de changement, en surmontant vos différends.</li>
    <li>Consulter un tiers autorisé (psychologue, conseiller familial, prêtre) à titre individuel pour faire le point sur votre situation personnelle.</li>
    <li>Consulter un conseiller/médiateur familial avec votre conjoint.</li>
    <li>Vous séparer de fait (sans requérir l'intervention d'un</li>
    <li>juge, et avec ou sans une convention écrite avec votre conjoint).</li>
    <li>Requérir du juge des mesures protectrices de l'union conjugale  (en demandant ou non  l'attribution du logement familial, c'est-à-dire en menant ou non une vie séparée).</li>
    <li>À noter que requérir des mesures protectrices de l'union conjugale pour organiser la vie séparée peut-être un moyen de préparer un divorce unilatéral si le conjoint refuse de divorcer.</li>
    <li>Si les conditions en sont réalisées, introduire une action en séparation de corps (cas échéant d'accord avec votre conjoint).</li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to control that. Any of the following options would address the issue for me:

1. The line breaks to the next column but does not create a new `<li>`
2. The column height grows only enough to allow the `<li>` not to break
   onto a new column.
3. The `<li>` does not break mid-sentence, but
   rather if it is too long to display in the column, it breaks before
   the `<li>`

The site can be viewed here: http://alisamii.dyndns.org/ergonomiq/domains/clients/sosd2/

If this requires custom coding (I am a novice at jQuery) then I would be happy to contract out the modifications to someone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest version (1.1). now the problem has been solved

Comment: Hi Fabio. I have v1.1. In fact, you made the modifications in the code to address my request. If you notice, I asked this question on 07/11/2012. However, aside from the above mentioned changes, far more functionality was needed and I had to finally hire a developer to write a script that functions as I need.